# Adding edge attribute causes TypeError: 'AtlasView' object does not support item assignment

Tags: networkx

Using networkx 2.0 I try to dynamically add an additional edge attribute by looping through all the edges. The graph is a MultiDiGraph.

According to the [tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#edge-attributes) it seems to be possible to add edge attributes the way I do in the code below:

```
g = nx.read_gpickle("../pickles/" + gname)
yearmonth = gname[:7]
g.name = yearmonth  # works
for source, target in g.edges():
    g[source][target]['yearmonth'] = yearmonth
```

This code throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'AtlasView' object does not support item assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work. Can you try a minimal example like `g = nx.Graph(); g.add_nodes_from([0, 1]); g.add_edge(0, 1); g[0][1]['a']='b'`?

Comment: It happens with just `G = nx.Graph()`. Why don't you try-check it before commenting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should happen if your graph is a `nx.MultiGraph`. From which case you need an extra index going from `0` to `n` where `n` is the number of  edges between the two nodes.

Try:

```
for source, target in g.edges():
    g[source][target][0]['yearmonth'] = yearmonth
```

The tutorial example is intended for a  `nx.Graph`.