# Export multiplex, directed graph with networkx

Tags: networkx

I'm trying to build, from a csv file, a multiplex, directed graph where each edge has a timestamp. I want to export it to Gephi for analysis as a dynamic graph.

The csv file looks like this:

```
cdv = [['id','timestamp', 'node 1', 'node 2', 'description']
['1','10', '1', '2', 'description']
['2','20', '1', '3', 'description']
['3,'30', '2', '3', 'description']]
etc.
```

The code to build the graph is:

```
def csv2gexf(csvf):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph() # works with G = nx.DiGraph()
    for f in csv:
        if f[3] not in G:
            G.add_node(f[3])
        if f[2] not in G:
            G.add_node(f[2])
            G.node[f[2]]['description'] = f[4]
        if G.has_edge(f[3], f[2]):
            G.edge[f[3]][f[2]]['weight'] += 1.0
        else:
            G.add_edge(f[3], f[2])
            G.edge[f[3]][f[2]]['timestamp'] = str(f[1])
            G.edge[f[3]][f[2]]['weight'] = 1.0
    nx.write_gexf(G, "graph.gexf")
```

While this code works when using a DiGraph instead of a MultiDiGraph, the later gives me this:

```
    nx.write_gexf(G, "graph.gexf")
  File "<decorator-gen-206>", line 2, in write_gexf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 220, in _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 77, in write_gexf
    writer.add_graph(G)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 300, in add_graph
    self.add_edges(G,graph_element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 355, in add_edges
    for u,v,key,edge_data in edge_key_data(G):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 340, in edge_key_data
    edge_data=data.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I thought gexf file format was supposed to handle multiplex directed graphs, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work -- I added a missing index required for the MultiDiGraph case; replace it with required data as needed. Note in 2.x the `edge` attribute is replaced with `adj`:

```
def csv2gexf(csvf):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph() # works with G = nx.DiGraph()
    for f in csv:
        if f[3] not in G:
            G.add_node(f[3])
        if f[2] not in G:
            G.add_node(f[2])
            G.node[f[2]]['description'] = f[4]
        if G.has_edge(f[3], f[2]):
            G.adj[f[3]][f[2]]['weight'] += 1.0
        else:
            G.add_edge(f[3], f[2])
            G.adj[f[3]][f[2]][0]['timestamp'] = str(f[1])  
            G.adj[f[3]][f[2]][0]['weight'] = 1.0
    nx.write_gexf(G, "graph.gexf")
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283340/adding-edge-attribute-causes-typeerror-atlasview-object-does-not-support-item

Comment: Thanks a lot! When importing into Gephi, the import window tells me it's not a dynamic graph, any idea why? "timestamp" should maybe be called something else?